# SSL page only loading in private network

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I have got a activated virtual hosts config for ssl like this:

```
<VirtualHost vidanalysis.com:443>
    ServerName vidanalysis.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/privkey.pem

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vidanalysis_html
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is my site can only be reach as https in my private network! What could be the problem?

Comment: You seem to be running your web site from home. Did you forward the port? Is your firewall open?

Comment: Thanks man! I think I would never have found my problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to forward the port(s) on your router, to the box you are hosting the site from.